# Will the toString() method of StringBuilder or StringBuffer create a new immutable String?

Tags: java

As we know, a java String is immutable and to create mutable String we can use `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`. Now if we have a String in a StringBuilder object and we use the `toString()` method of it, will that create another immutable String in the String pool. If so, then how avoid such situation.

Comment: Why do you need to avoid it? `StringBuffer`/`StringBuilder` are used to manipulate `char dynamic arrays` in memory in an efficient way (without having to create a new `String` object at each operation). the `toString()` will return the construct of the operations done on that char dynamic array as a `string` which is therefore `immutable`.

Comment: You can't have mutable `String` objects. You can however use the interface `CharSequence` for both `String`  and `StringBuilder`.

Comment: our main purpose of using StringBuilder is to avoid immutable Strings now, if using the toString ends up in creating another String as the same content of the StringBuilder, then the purpose is somehow violated with the implementation.

Comment: *will that create another immutable String in the String pool...* As opposed to what? It's not very clear what you're looking for.

Comment: I wanted to avoid creating the immutable Strings, but i had some misconceptions which @Ernest  and Eran clarified very well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Now if we have a String in a StringBuilder object and we use the toString() method of it, will that create another immutable String in the String pool

You don't have a `String` in the `StringBuilder`. The characters are stored in a `char[]`, and when you call `toString()`, a new `String` is created:

```
public String toString() {
    // Create a copy, don't share the array
    return new String(value, 0, count);
}
```

That said, creating a new `String` doesn't add it to the `String` pool, so there's nothing for you to avoid.

> our main purpose of using StringBuilder is to avoid immutable Strings

That's not accurate. The main purpose is to avoid creation of multiple `String`s as a result of multiple `String` concatenations. Using `StringBuilder` allows you to perform all the concatenations with a single `StringBuilder` instance. If you want a `String` representation of the contents of the `StringBuilder`, you can't avoid creating one `String` instance. However, you don't have to create a `String` representation of the `StringBuilder` contents (unless you need to pass it to a method that requires a `String`).

Answer (score 7):

The implementation of `toString()` in those classes look like:

```
return new String(value, 0, count); // StringBuilder
return new String(toStringCache, true); // StringBuffer
```

These aren't literals, they're creating a new `String` object which will not end up in the string pool.

Answer (score 1):

**YES** , it will create another instance of an string when you call **toString()** on StringBuilder Object

If you want to avoid that, you can just modify the return type of the method to StringBuilder instead of String, if that is the case, and can progress with the StringBuilder Object

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder and StringBuffer extends AbstractStringBuilder. the String values passed to any of these class finally calls **"putStringAt(int index, String str)"** method in AbstractStringBuilder, Its implementation is Defined below,

```
private final void putStringAt(int index, String str) {
    if (getCoder() != str.coder()) {
        inflate();
    }
    str.getBytes(value, index, coder); //value is byte[]
}
```

As we can see that it is copying input String str values to byte array named value (after validating as it is a different value). So we need not worry about any other String variable inside StringBuilder or StringBuffer

Now to your question, Yes object for String will be created on call of toString method.

StringBuilder and StringBuffer are defined for the different set of operations. You need not call toString method if you have restriction over String pool